# Manually Stop a Running Task

Tags: tasker

Is there a way to stop a specific Tasker task from running?

I can see the task in the Run Log but even when I go to the specific task that is running but there isn't a stop button.
This happens whether the task is manually started from a shortcut or from a profile.

On the other hand, there is a stop button when starting the task directly from inside the task editor.

Comment: Hi! I request clarification. Why do you want to do that? May I suggest you give the actual problem in  hand. Why use the task at first place if you don't want it to run?

Comment: Lets say there is a task that runs on a schedule but i want to interrupt it today. E.g. backup, timer, etc

Comment: In that particular case, you can create a new task and use the action stop to stop a particular task. You can either execute it manually if the intended task is already running so that the latter stops, or bind the new task to a profile such as If today then stop XYZ task.

Comment: Haha clever. I like that. And can also make the particular task accept name of task as a variable. Would be nice to be able to kill task in the Run Log though.

Comment: Firelord, I suggest reposting your comment as an answer so that it can be accepted and the question closed.